# Clicking in AMSlideMenu and Load URL into multiple Web View iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This is my first attempts for an iOS app... :-)

With the help of AMSlideMenu (https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu) I have created a left and a right swipe menu.

After clicking on the different menu items I would like to have different websites to load.
For that I have appointed to the View Controller a Web View.

[image: Right-Swipe Menu with Web View]

Now I have no idea how I can link these WebViews with my MainVC.m where I can do the requests for the different websites:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //load url into webview
    NSString *strURL = @"http://test.com/DEMO/index.html";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webviewInfo loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

Hope someone can help me or has a better idea to load the web pages. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showOfferDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        OfferDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.offer = [offers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```